# Viewpager in Android: Adjust image size for a slider

Tags: java, android, image, android-viewpager, slider

I made an image slider based on [THIS](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) 
I see that I cannot import drawables standard sizes, because the top bar takes space and the image appear distorted! I cannot use vector, the pics are JPG. What would be a proper size of the imported pic for this kind of application?

[SCREENSHOT HERE: The image looks distorted...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMtuF.jpg)